# Circuit to light up LED only once

Tags: led, batteries, low-power, pulse

I have a battery-powered product with an ON/OFF switch with two leads. I am looking for a circuit to shine a LED for a short duration each time the switch goes from OFF to ON. Power consumption and cost are of great importance, so any leakage current or similar has to be absolutely minimal; 0.1 μA is too much. The LED pulse needs to be big enough to be noticeable when looking directly at it. The device does not turn on and off often.

I was thinking about charging a capacitor when the switch is open and then dumping that energy through the LED (plus disconnecting the cap) when the switch is closed. What would that look like? What about considerations for leakage?
Other ideas are welcome too!

[image: Sketch]

Comment: 100 nA is going to be a tough goal. I think it can be done. Just saying. Also, would it be okay to require the switch to be released after triggering the LED for a period? Or does it have to work such that the LED goes off even if the switch remains firmly held active?

Comment: https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/waveforms/monostable.html   You're welcome

Comment: @KyleB Do any of those come close to 100 nA when quiescent? If so, I probably missed it and wouldn't mind getting a clue. Thanks.

Comment: @jonk, as indicated in my diagram the switch will remain closed.

Comment: @KyleB Thank you. Proper terms are always very helpful. I will look more into this!

Comment: @OhmInpw That fact eliminates one circuit I know would meet your 100 nA requirement. Adds complexity now. I'll let it gestate a bit. I gather you do have some requirement for the release and then re-assertion, that you haven't yet stated. I'll hold short until I hear more about that part.

Comment: @jonk The use case is quite simple. The user needs a visual indication that the device was powered on. One the does not draw current while the device remains on nor draws any current while the device is turned off.

Comment: @KyleB A monostable multivibrator sounds like it would do the trick! My only concern is that the output pulse is perhaps a tad too short. But that is probably solvable with discrete solutions.
From looking quickly at parts I found several solutions that would satisfy the Iq requirement. Like this one at 0.02 uA: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4047b.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1663885760519&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fcd4047b

Comment: I thank you both for your input. My load contains an MCU and I think I'll design for a firmware-based solution.
I do consider the suggestion from @KyleB a solution to the problem I posed here.

Comment: There are microcontrollers with ridiculously low sleep mode power consumption, so you could have any behaviour you like. For example, SiLabs C8051F98x can go as low as 10nA: https://www.silabs.com/mcu/8-bit-microcontrollers/c8051f98x

Comment: Have you looked at LT's TimerBlox series? I don't know if they hit 100 nA, but they have pretty low leakage, and there's a wide variety of timing-related stuff available. Though LT parts seem to be particularly affected by the ongoing semiconductor shortage, so it might not be easy to get them *now*.

Comment: You can just put a cap in series with the LED.

Comment: Or put a cap in series with the base of a BJT. The BJT can turn on the LED. I believe you can get below 0.1uA.

Comment: See cct added to my answer -  50 nA or less quiescent. Not as good as Joseph's 100 fA :-)

Comment: I seen in your comment that you are entertaining a microprocessor based solution. In my experience, that is the most common way (by far) to do this sort of thing. During boot up, the processor could turn on the LED for some amount of time and then turn it off. This also gives you the flexibility to control the on-time duration of the LED pretty easily without any component changes.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv37PX.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Dare I suggest something as crude as the circuit above?  The only quiescent current is the leakage through the capacitor.  D2 is there to help discharge the capacitor when the switch is off.  Or it could be be removed, and a very large (>10M) resistor added across the capacitor.

Answer (score 3):

The [74C14 (unbuffered) hex schmitt inverter](https://media.digikey.com/pdf/Data%20Sheets/Fairchild%20PDFs/MM74C14.pdf) has a static whole package (6 inverters) current of typically 50 nA at 15V supply and maximum 15 uA across the temperature range. At 25C it will usually be close to the typocal value. At 5V supply it will be lower and at the maximum alllowed supply of 3 V lower again.

The [CD40106 hex schmitt trigger {buffered}](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd40106b.pdf?HQS=dis-dk-null-digikeymode-dsf-pf-null-wwe&ts=1663984995961&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fgeneral%252Fdocs%252Fsuppproductinfo.tsp%253FdistId%253D10%2526gotoUrl%253Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fcd40106b) has a 50 nA typical quiescent package current at 25 degree C and 1 uA maximum. At 3V it will be lower again.

It will be easy to built a monostable based on schmitt inverters that meet your requirements.

---

Gates must be schmitt triggered.

3V, 25 C, 74C14 - Well under 50 nA quiescent typical.
5V, 25 C, CD40106 - 50 nA typical

RC sets pulse period.
R2 not needed if Vin is always high or low.
D1 not essential - aids recovery time after Vin falls.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOKhUC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: I guess "R3" is supposed to be "R2"?

Comment: @OskarSkog  R3 not needed so wan't there :-) :-) :-) - || THanks - yes - edited.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this will work. I didn't simulate it. But some variation should work.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fyB7gI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Might need a resistor in series with the base also. And you might get away with R1 being quite small. The idea is you could over-drive the LED to make a nice bright flash. Probably you could get away with this since you never light up the LED continuously.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this circuit below
[image: timer circuit]

The circuit above is done by 555 timer. When the circuit is in off state it consumes about 353ua current.
When the circuit is in off state the capacitor charges through pin 6 and 7 connected to positive voltage source. when the switch is been pressed, it connects pin 2 to ground which causes an astable state that makes the capacitor shut circuit and is totally discharged. It then charges through pin 6 and 7, in the charging state of the capacitor, the circuit is on which means current flows out through pin 3 and it can be connected to load. When the capacitor reached the minimum voltage needed by the timer it turns of the timer no current flow through pin 3  waiting for another trigger from pin 2.

Note that by modifying the resistor values on pin 7 and the capacitor value, the charging time of the capacitor chenges too, you can also do that with the help of the pot to change the charging time. And modifying the value of the (pot, resistor on pin 7 and the capacitor) , the current consumed in off state changes too.

I might not be good in explanation but i think when you simulate it yourself, you will understand better.

I decide to use an npn transistor for driving the load but you can also connect it directly to the load.
You can remove the transistor like below
[image: 555 timer 2]

Comment: Also note that when you pressed the switch and the circuit is in on state, if you pressed the switch again simultaneously it will not result in longer charging time which means the circuit will ignore the trigger until it gets back to off state. Example: if you set it to 1 minute on time, when the switch is being pressed the counting startes from the first trigger(press) till the next 1 minute even if the circuit is remaining 10 seconds to complete 1 minute and you press the switch again, it won't reset it instead it will ignore the trigger till it gets back to off state

Comment: Not even in the same universe as 100 nA, quiescent.

Comment: You could use a push button instead of a switch and use a 555 timer in a monostable circuit setup where when you push the button the light stays on for a couple of seconds and turns off.

Comment: A 555 is *extremely* power-hungry. You're orders of magnitude over the current limit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the circuit I mentioned in my comment last night.

In my case, the output fed an I/O to a microprocessor.   You won't be able to light an LED directly with this, instead you'd probably sent 'output' to a MOSFET gate.

The pulse duration is controlled by C1.  Clearly the low quiescent current is achieved by the very high value resistors used.

To trigger the circuit, as shown you would close the switch.  In your circuit, you might AC couple Q1's base to your load.   Basically it just needs to be 'tickled' to get it to trigger.

If you wanna try pursuing this, write back and we can work through your implementation.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9CMvC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

A reset / power monitor device can do this, and consume very little power in the process.

0.1uA may be difficult to attain however. This one’s less than 2uA: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/supervisors-voltage-monitors-sequencers/MAX835.html

And this one claims 125nA: https://www.maximintegrated.com/en/products/power/supervisors-voltage-monitors-sequencers/MAX16056.html. Close enough?

Answer (score 0):

Here is another circuit, it consumes about 100 fa current when not used
[image: npn timer]

Push the button to turn on the circuit, you can adjust the on time by tuning the potentiometer or changing the value of the capacitor along with the resistor and the potentiometer.

Comment: This does not meet the requirement, as the relay is on at all times that the push-button is depressed. The circuit could be modified to work. See my answer or mkeith's for a suitable capacitor arrangement.

Comment: fA? Femto Ampere?